# find the min in the vector but no 0

Tags: r, dplyr

My df is like this

```
  df <- data.frame(t1 = c(10, 20, 30, 1, 0), t2 = c(30, 0, 40, 0, 0), t3 = c(10, 0, 3, 10, 0))
```

what I want to do is to find the `min` in the `df` row but not 0
I do

```
df<- df%>% rowwise() %>%
  do({
    th <- c(.$t1, .$t2, .$t3,)


    data.frame(., t_s_last = min(th[th > 0))
  })
```

but it works but not for the rows that contain sth more than 0.
how to make this returning 0 if there are just 0 in the row (row 5)?

Comment: Are you values are always integers >= 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` with an `if/else` condition

```
 apply(df, 1, function(x) if(all(x==0)) 0 else min(x[x> 0]))
```

Or another option is `rowMins` from `library(matrixStats)`.  We replace the '0' values in the dataset with `NA`, use `rowMins` with `na.rm=TRUE`, and replace the 'Inf' values with 0.

```
 library(matrixStats)
 is.na(df) <- df==0
 v1 <- rowMins(as.matrix(df), na.rm=TRUE)
 v1[is.infinite(v1)] <- 0
 v1
 #[1] 10 20  3  1  0
```

We can also use the `if/else` within the `do`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({th <- unlist(.[.>0])
       data.frame(., t_s_last = if(all(th==0)) 0 else min(th))})
#  t1 t2 t3 t_s_last
#1 10 30 10       10
#2 20  0  0       20
#3 30 40  3        3
#4  1  0 10        1
#5  0  0  0        0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like `dplyr` so I will mark this answer

Comment: @Mateusz1981  No problem.  Glad to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that because you are looking for values above zero, all your values **are >=0 and integers**. Thus, we could play around with log transformation in order to convert all the zeroes to `Inf` and thus being always the largest. This will help us avoid running by row operations, rather vectorize using the minus of the `max.col` function

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(-abs(log(df))))]
## [1] 10 20  3  1  0
```

Comment: taking absolute value of the log will screw up the ordering - compare `abs(log(0.2))` vs `abs(log(1.2))`

Comment: @eddi that only true for non-integer values. I've edited the answer

Comment: Doesn't have to be integers, just need to have no numbers between 0 and 1. Maybe you can fix with smth like `log(df) + 1000` - I think that covers the smallest numbers R can represent.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but restricting to *x in (0 | >=1)* seems awkward to me. I'm guessing OP has integers >= 0 (I'e asked him). If not, I'll probably delete as this is getting ridiculously specific

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`. A bit longer than answer from @akrun. But possibly more readable without the use of `do`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(time, value, t1:t3) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ts = ifelse(all(value == 0), 0, min(value[value != 0])))  %>%
  spread(time, value)
```